# Rails: How do you use a search query to find a belongs_to item as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, belongs-to

What I need is to search for Story titles as well as who the story belongs to all in one search.

Obviously this isn't right but it gets my point across:

```
@stories = Story.where("user.display_name LIKE ? And title LIKE ?", 
             "%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%").limit(500).page(params[:page])
```

Stories belong to users and users have many stories.  Not sure what else I need to put here and I haven't really understood any answers that seem to be related.

Thanks.

UPDATE

```
<% if @stories.size == 0 %>
    Sorry, there were no stories found.
<% else %>
    <table class="sortableTable table-striped" style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th width="55%">Title</th>
         <th width="25%">User</th>
         <th width="10%">Created At</th>
         <th width="10%">Updated At</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @stories.each do |s| %>
        <tr>
         <td width="55%"><div class="span5 search_result"><%= link_to s.title, s %></div></td>
         <td width="25%"><div class="span3 search_result"><%= link_to s.user.display_name, s.user %></div></td>
         <td width="10%"><div class="span3 search_result"><%= time_ago_in_words(s.created_at) %> ago</div></td>
         <td width="10%"><div class="span3 search_result"><%= time_ago_in_words(s.updated_at) %> ago</div></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

      </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to eager load the user object associated with the story:

```
Story.joins(:user).where(
   "users.display_name LIKE :term And stories.title LIKE :term", 
   :term =>  "%#{@query}%"
).limit(500).page(params[:page])
```

If you want to eager load the user object associated with the story:

```
Story.includes(:user).where(
   "users.display_name LIKE :term And stories.title LIKE :term", 
   :term =>  "%#{@query}%"
).limit(500).page(params[:page])
```

**Note:**

I am using the placeholder condition in the where clause as the same query term is used in two places.

Comment: Thanks, tried it and it didn't seem to work.  I got this error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user.display_name: SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "stories" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "stories"."user_id" WHERE (user.display_name LIKE '%%%%%' And title LIKE '%%%%%') LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count.  The codes you supplied were both the same as well, not sure if that was intentional.  Thanks!

Comment: Changed it to:  Story.joins(:user).where( "display_name LIKE :term And title LIKE :term", :term => "%#{@query}%").limit(500).page(params[:page])  and now it at least searches without errors, but still won't pull anything up that corresponds to a user's display name.

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: I updated the question as well to show you the code I have to display results, thinking maybe there is an issue with it.  If I type in a search for a story I know exists, there is no problem, if I search for a user that I know exists, nothing comes up.

Comment: Is it an `AND` condition or an `OR` condition? From your description it looks like an OR condition to me, i.e., `users.display_name LIKE :term OR stories.title LIKE :term`.

Comment: And with that it is fixed!  Thank you good sir.  I have much to learn.